# Workflow to change a managed metadata field in form when current date/time is greater than EndDate

Tags: workflow, managed-metadata

I am working in a document library. I have a field, SessionType, that is a managed metadata field which can contain either a value of "Upcoming" or a value of "Past session". In addition, each item in the library has an EventDate and EndDate.

I'd like to make a workflow that changes the value of the SessionType from "Upcoming" to "Past session" when the current date/time is greater than the EndDate.

I'm not sure how best to write this workflow. Should it be a timer job? If so, how would I write that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workflow should do the trick. This is how I would do it :

Start on item created/modified

> Set EndDate in a workflow variable
>
> Parallel Block
>
> Block 1 (set the status when end date is reached):
>
> > Pause until EndDate
> >
> > then Update list item with the new status
> >
> > then Stop the workflow
>
> Block 2 (stop the workflow if EndDate has changed):
>
> > Wait for EndDate to not equal EndDate workflow variable
> >
> > then Stop the workflow